# Gerund as a noun 'having/taking a shower'

Tags: gerunds, nouns, gerund-clauses

Can I use the phrase 'having/taking a shower' as a noun when it supposed to be present simple tense

Example:

> I wake up then (I) **having** a shower

---

Examples that I found:

[1](http://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/translation/taking+shower.html) use less water when washing their hands, **brushing** their teeth, or **taking** a shower

[2](https://twitter.com/itswillyferrell/status/391927169313964032) Finishing a good movie, and then **having** to face the reality of your boring life

[3](http://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/nouns/gerunds/) Let’s go **dancing** at the club tonight

[3.1](http://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/nouns/gerunds/) **Swimming** in the ocean has been Sharon’s passion since she was five years old

[4](https://youtu.be/6XUnG0OfEgE?t=62) **Wearing** loose pants while riding a bicycle is dangerous

[5](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/taking) So more **eating**, more **drinking** and more **taking** of photos - many of them painfully embarrassing

---

Question:

Can I use the phrase *'having a shower'* instead of have a shower in present simple cases *(I wake up then (I) **having** a shower)*?

Comment: Your *I wake up then (I) having a shower* is completely ungrammatical regardless of whether you repeat the subject ***I*** or not. In principle you could say things like *He awoke having a headache* or *I awoke hearing the alarm clock* (these are syntactically valid constructions). But in practice we'd more likely say *He awoke **with** a headache* or *I awoke **to** the alarm clock*.

Comment: Of your examples, the only one which is at all similar to the structure in the example is 2. And example 2 is not a complete sentence with a finite verb. It is just a noun phrase, understood to be a subject complement, the subject is implied by the question which is being answered.The twitter game is to suggest questions to which that could be the answer.

Answer (score 4):

No. Your underlying sentence *I wake up and then I have a shower* consists of two independent clauses. You may delete the repeated subject, but the second clause requires a finite verb.

Note also that *I wake up and then I am having a shower* is not acceptable either. Whether the simple present *I wake up* is deployed in a habitual sense ("On weekdays I wake up") or a narrative sense ("The alarm goes off. I wake up."), it is incompatible with a progressive continuation.

Comment: He can say, "**I wake up, then after having a shower I brush my teeth.**"

Comment: @SovereignSun- Could it also be "Then, having had a shower..."? But the context is: The first thing I do after I wake up is taking a shower. Why put all eggs in one basket where there is a definite sequence of habitual actions? I mean the sentence you are suggesting. Do you agree?

Comment: @SovereignSun There, however, the shower is in a subordinate clause.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use the phrase 'having/taking a shower' as a noun

Yes, mostly.

> ... when it supposed to be present simple tense

No.  Gerunds cannot substitute for simple present tense.  Note that *{form of to be} + ing* is a progressive or continuous verb form and not a gerund.

> I wake up then (I) having a shower

Couple of problems here:

- Gerunds don't take subjects.  Simplifying things - they kinda-sorta can, but you use object or possessive pronouns instead of subject pronouns.  E.g. *Me having a shower was refreshing or *My having a shower worried her*.
- *X then Y* - *then* joins clauses, not nouns.  So Y can't be noun or gerund, but Y can "recycle" head elements from X which can be elided.  E.g. *I woke up then showered = I woke up then I showered*.
- So something like *I went walking then running* will work because it's really *I went walking then I went running*.